# How to structure one Git repo for three different customers

Tags: git, project-management, git-workflow

We're building a project, which will be shipped to three different customers. Gitlab will be used for version control.

For each customer the features are gonna be somewhat different, e.g. different pages or different form validations.

Lacking experience, we struggle to identify the right structure for our repo.

One idea was, to have a master branch with common code. 
Then create a branch for each customer. Those branches are gonna be deployed later. For each customer branch there could be a feature branch, which could be used for testing and developing new customer related features.
Changes on master could be merged into the customer branches as needed.
Master branch would have its own dev branch.

Would be glad for all constructive input

Comment: Don’t confuse source control with dependency management.

Comment: Is there a way to combine this in our use case? The project will be relatively small, ~10.000 lines of code in total

Comment: Have one repo for “core” and other client specific repos which depend on the core. This is likely to be language specific.

Comment: Should have added that: it's a web-app using Angular + TypeScript

Comment: Use another tool which is better suited to dependency management. Like a private npm registry, or similar.

Comment: Is it possible to make the software configureable, i.e. have a single repository and enable and disable pages or validation based on a customer-specific configuration file or something?

Comment: So, if I understand you right: We'd create a repo with the core application.
Then for each customer a seperate repo. For every build we include a certain customer repo as a dependency?

Comment: Or is it possible to have the core functionality as a submodule in each customer repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have differents customer specific code on one repository. Make a repository for each customer : they can make their own update. Then, if the core need some upgrade commons for all customer, they can pull it from the original repository. Cleaner and easier for everyone (a customer doesn't need to know the what happend for the others).

Comment: Thanks for your input! Maybe I articulated myself wrong.
We build one aplication, that will be used by different customers. The project will look almost similar for all of them, tho we'll have different endpoints for each customer and some additional pages for some customers.
My question is: we have a core application that'll stay the same. Customer specific code we wanna keep seperated from that.

Comment: Yeah. The initial repository one, yours, the one that will have the core features shared for all repositories. Then your customers repositories : I assumed that they should be able to do some update themselves at some point ? The others repositories will be the customers one so : they can pull from the original one the core modifications and have their own.

Comment: Thanks :) So, we'd somehow have to clone the core repo for each customer and git pull from the customer repo, everytime the core updates?

Comment: The finality of a branch is to be merged at some point : if you keep one branch for each customer, then create one branch per feature for each customer... The git history won't be a breeze to read, without taking in account the risk of merging the wrong branch, etc.

Comment: Yup, you just have to fork the original repository (the core one), then you can add the original repository in the fetching branch for each customer repository : https://help.github.com/en/articles/merging-an-upstream-repository-into-your-fork